# Cannot find executable GMSCoreResources.bundle

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

After upgrading to google maps sdk 1.4 I'm receiving the following error:

Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x175e52e0 /var/mobile/Applications/-/-.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCoreResources.bundle> (not loaded)

When migrating I replaced both bundle and framework, and everything looks good (GMSCoreResouces.bundle is inside GoogleMaps.bundle).

Any Ideas?

Comment: same problem, no solution for now!

Comment: Claimed as fixed in 1.5 https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5640&can=1&q=Cannot%20find%20executable&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its already fixed on 1.5 version

Comment: But it is not support 5.1 ios

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a clean and rebuild. If that doesn't help delete the bundle and resource from your project and re add them.